# What is the purpose of p-Template in PrimeNG?

Tags: angular, user-interface, primeng

I am new to PrimeNG.
I am using the menubar component and it looks like this:

```
<p-menubar [model]="items">
<ng-template pTemplate="start">
    <img src="assets/primeng.svg" height="40" class="p-mr-2">
</ng-template>
<ng-template pTemplate="end">
    <input type="text" pInputText placeholder="Search">
</ng-template>
```

**What is the purpose of the pTemplate in the ng-Template element?**

I cannot display anything inside the ng-template.

Answer (score 1):

pTemplate is a directive and you can use it by importing the PrimeTemplate module in your app.module.ts as shown below screenshot.

[image]